# Short Riley Is Finally Here!

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

Another Short (At least for me) Riley :D

> My Prefix is a famous man
>
> Made many incredible *things* and I love them all
>
> My Infix produces most of the stuff I wear
>
> I think it came from the UK
>
> My Suffix is what my prefix has done
>
> It always soothes my mind
>
> My Whole comes from the neighboring country of one of the most dangerous ones

What am I?

Hint :

> I believe many have or had used *the word*

Hint 2 :

> The prefix is only the first name of the famous man

Comment: Would the [tag:trivia]/[tag:knowledge] tags be appropriate here?

Comment: Hmm, it does include knowledge I guess. Thanks for telling me :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Samsung

My Prefix is a famous man

Made many incredible things and I love them all

> **Sam** - which I think might be singer Sam Smith, but I'm not sure.

My Infix produces most of the stuff I wear

I think it came from the UK

> **M**&**S** - short for Marks and Spencers

My Suffix is what my prefix has done

It always soothes my mind

> **Sung** - This is why I think it is a singer

My Whole comes from the neighboring country of one of the most dangerous ones

> As mentioned by AHKieran, Samsung is from South Korea, neighbour of North Korea.

Comment: Yep you are absolutely correct. Sam Smith is a good singer so I thought I would include him in a Riley riddle. Will accept tomorrow :D

Comment: Ah well done! I wasn't sure of SK exports and had looked up car models but nothing fit :P Good spot!

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

Whole:

> I'm thinking the most dangerous country referenced might be North Korea, so the whole would then be a South Korean export, if they mean literal neighbour, or Japanese export, if they also mean across the water.

Prefix:

> Shigeru Miyamoto is the head of Nintendo, who make lots of video games which OP may love, this may translate to the prefix of 'SM'

Suffix:

> A nintendo product i.e. pokemon or gameboy, but initialised like the prefix.

Comment: Well, the 'whole' section is on the right track but both the prefix and suffix is not :D